# django rest auth email validation

Tags: django, rest, validation, email, django-rest-auth

Can someone explain how to set up email verification for django rest auth ?
My settings.py contains:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True   
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

And I've added this line in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

But when I register with this endpoint: `rest-auth/registration/`, the email is not sent, but the user is created.
What is the good configuration to send email confirmation? Do I have to have a SMTP server?

**EDIT:** (after @McAbra comment)

Obviously, this setting cannot send email:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

It only print the mail in the django console output.
The settings given by @McAbra works well.
But in a production environment, is it a good practice to send verification email with gmail?
Have I just to create email such `noreply.myapp@gmail.com`?

**EDIT 2:**

My other problem is that the sent mail is empty. The template are presents in `site-packages\allauth\templates\account\email`. The email title is `[http://localhost:8000/]` but there is no content. I have no error in the python console. Any idea?

> Solution for this point:
>
> `site-packages\allauth\templates\account\email` files must be copied
>   in `your-app\templates\account\email`

Comment: Just to make sure: you are not expecting a real email, right? If you are using the `EMAIL_BACKEND` you specified you'll get an "email" printed out in your console.

Comment: I would like to set up a registration with verification by email. I'm looking for a solution to set my configuration to send a validation email to the user then proceed to the validation to activate the user account.

Comment: Ok, so you do get an email printed in your console but you want to send actual emails into a real mailbox?

Comment: Yes that's it. But I've just checked, I don't have anything printed in my console. I will update my post.

Comment: Oh... and I think it's Django allauth not "rest auth".

Comment: That solution is not the case - the template was most likely not accessible from it's original directory as you did not include `allauth` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I just checked, allauth is in my INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a SMTP server if you want to send real emails. I like to use Gmail SMTP server. `settings.py` would be:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'gmail_username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password from https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords'
```

Try from there. I'll try to help further if that doesn't help.

Comment: Your solution works, but I had to change EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD by simply the gmail account password. This url: `https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords` return `"The setting you are looking for is not available for your account."`

Comment: And I have edited my post with a short question, maybe you can help me on this point too? :)

Comment: Is there any reason why it works only on localhost and not in my server (with the same settings)?

Answer (score 3):

I had problems with sending emails and after that with the link in the email. You need to explicitly set the account confirm email view.

Below are my settings in settings.py

```
 ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
 ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True   
 ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
 ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
```

in urls.py

```
  from allauth.account.views import confirm_email as allauthemailconfirmation

  urlpatterns  = [
  url(r'^api/rest-auth/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$',allauthemailconfirmation,
    name='account_confirm_email'),
  ]
```

You can use [mailcatcher.me](https://mailcatcher.me/) if you want to check emails locally.